# Не могу решить задачку. Операторы ввода/вывода, Параметры вывода

Tags: c++

Подскажите, что не так. По условию вроде правильно, насколько я понял, но проверку не проходит. Может я условие не так понял, подскажите пожалуйста.

**Ресурс:** http://academy.cppstudio.com/

**Тема:** Операторы ввода/вывода, Параметры вывода.

**Условие:**

> Сделайте вывод трех произвольных целых чисел в три колонки шириной 15
>   символов. Свободное место в колонке заполните символом #. Колонки
>   должны быть разделены пробелом.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  /* ↓ Ваш код ↓ */

  cout << 1 << " ";
  cout.fill('#');
  cout.width(15);
  cout << " " << 2 << " ";
  cout.width(15);
  cout << " " << 3;

  return 0;
}
```

вывод : 1 ############## 2 ############## 3

Пробовал через **cin**, тожне идёт.

```
  int num0 = 0;
  int num1 = 1;
  int num2 = 2;

  cin >> num0;
  cin >> num1;
  cin >> num2;
```

Comment: Может так: `##############1 ##############2 ##############3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас почему-то после каждого числа пробел стоит, попробуйте его убрать. А ещё в последнем столбце у Вас не 15 символов. Короче говоря, попробуйте вот такое решение:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    /* ↓ Ваш код ↓ */

    cout.fill('#');
    cout.width(15);
    cout << left << 1 << " ";
    cout.width(15);
    cout << left << 2 << " ";
    cout.width(15);
    cout << left << 3;

    return 0;
}
```

`std::left` можете заменить на `std::right`, в условии не сказано на какой позиции должны быть числа.

Comment: Верно, позиция не оговорена. прошел код:
`#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    /* ↓ Ваш код ↓ */

    cout.fill('#');
    cout.width(15);
    cout << 1 << " ";
    cout.width(15);
    cout << 2 << " ";
    cout.width(15);
    cout << 3;

    return 0;
}`
однако я в начале основывался на том, что рядом с цифрами должен быть пробел. И в последнем столбце указывать `cout.width(15);` не видел смысла, т.к. результат показывал то, что нужно в условии. Насколько я понял его. :)

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

прошел код:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    /* ↓ Ваш код ↓ */

    cout.fill('#');
    cout.width(15);
    cout << 1 << " ";
    cout.width(15);
    cout << 2 << " ";
    cout.width(15);
    cout << 3;

    return 0;
}
```